# How to import an external DSC module into PowerShell environment?

Tags: powershell, dsc

I have Windows 10 / Windows 2016 TP5 (PowerShell 5.1). I want to use a PowerShell DSC module from GitHub in my configuration, for example [xTimeZone](https://github.com/PowerShell/xTimeZone).

What shall I do to be able to reference it with `Import-DSCResource`?

It's the first time I try to add a module other than from an installer-based product and maybe I am missing something obvious. Isn't there a `git clone`-based procedure like `pip` or `gem` utilise?

---

I verified the value of `$env:PSModulePath` and it has two directories defined: `C:\Users\techraf\Documents\WindowsPowerShell\Modules;C:\Windows\system32\W
indowsPowerShell\v1.0\Modules`.

I copied the contents of [xTimeZone](https://github.com/PowerShell/xTimeZone/tree/dev/DSCResources/xTimeZone) directory to `C:\Users\techraf\Documents\WindowsPowerShell\Modules`.

PowerShell does not see it. Tried to copy on different levels of the repository - all failed.

---

When running the [example](https://github.com/PowerShell/xTimeZone/blob/dev/Example/SetTimeZone.ps1) script I get:

```
At line:12 char:4
+    Import-DSCResource -ModuleName xTimeZone
+    ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
Could not find the module 'xTimeZone'.
At line:16 char:9
+         xTimeZone TimeZoneExample
+         ~~~~~~~~~
Undefined DSC resource 'xTimeZone'. Use Import-DSCResource to import the resource.
    + CategoryInfo          : ParserError: (:) [], ParseException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : ModuleNotFoundDuringParse
```

---

Per advice from the answer, after moving the module from `C:\Users\techraf\Documents\WindowsPowerShell\Modules` to `C:\Windows\system32\W
indowsPowerShell\v1.0\Modules` the first error disappeared and I get only:

```
At line:16 char:9
+         xTimeZone TimeZoneExample
+         ~~~~~~~~~
Undefined DSC resource 'xTimeZone'. Use Import-DSCResource to import the resource.
    + CategoryInfo          : ParserError: (:) [], ParentContainsErrorRecordException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : ResourceNotDefined
```

Comment: There are two different xTimeZone directories in play here, the outer directory which contains the PowerShell module. And the inner folder, under DSCResources. When you take this from github you need the entire module, the top level xTimeZone folder. That must be in your Modules folder.

Comment: This is the path structure you need: `WindowsPowerShell\Modules\xTimeZone\DSCResources\xTimeZone`.

Comment: Go here: https://github.com/PowerShell/xTimeZone/tree/master. "Clone or Download", select zip. Extract xTimeZone-master. Rename it to xTimeZone. Copy it to Program Files\WIndowsPowerShell\Modules. Test it can be discovered with `Get-DscResource`

Comment: Yes, yes. That was a combination of a few problems. I'm through it, but I bumped into a third hurdle now.

Comment: Updated the answer below to make it a bit more sane rather than spread over comments. What's the next error?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**About DSC resources**

DSC resources are, in essence, specialised PowerShell modules. The resource module must export Get, Set and Test-TargetResource commands (another option is available with PowerShell 5, but out of scope in the context of xTimeZone).

Resources are always deployed in the following structure:

```
<Modules>\<ModuleName>\DSCResources\<ResourceName>
```

Get-DscResource looks for "modules" inside the DSCResources folder, as a sub-folder of an existing module. If it can't see the resource you cannot use it.

**xTimeZone**

xTimeZone consists of:

1. A PowerShell module which contains little more than a manifest and some examples.
2. A DSC resource named xTimeZone.

Windows PowerShell cannot find the resource unless it's correctly deployed. These instructions apply for downloading the module.

1. Select the master branch and download the zip of the repository from: https://github.com/PowerShell/xTimeZone/tree/master
2. Extract the zip file to a folder.
3. Rename `xTimeZone-master` to `xTimeZone`.
4. Copy `xTimeZone` to `C:\Program Files\WindowsPowerShell\Modules`
5. Verify you can discover the DSCResource:

   ```
   Get-DscResource
   ```

If, for some reason, you're having problems with Program Files\Modules, you might use:

```
C:\WINDOWS\system32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\Modules\
```

However, as this area is part of the operating systems files it's a lower preference.

**Configuration**

Once you can discover the resource, you need to import it into each Configuration element in which you wish to use it.

```
Configuration SomeConfiguration {
    Import-DscResource -ModuleName xTimeZone

    # Nodes statement follows
}
```

Comment: One more addition to your answer: files required running `unblock-file` ([reference](https://powershell.org/forums/topic/testing-configurations-and-other-quirks/page/2/#post-18326)) otherwise I was getting: `Importing module xTimeZone failed with error - File C:\Program Files\WindowsPowerShell\Modules\xTimeZone\DscResources\TimezoneHelper.psm1 cannot be loaded because you opted not to run this software now.`

Answer (score 0):

*Not trying to answer, just wanted to put in additional feedback, but don't have enough stack-street-cred to add a comment...

Depending on the DSC you're trying to use, sometimes you have to copy the content from the "source" folder (that contains aforementioned "modules" and "DSCResources" sub folders) up to the root of the dscname you're trying to work with.  In my instance I was using the SqlServerDsc (url below) and am not overly versed so it took a while to figure out what was going on.

https://github.com/dsccommunity/SqlServerDsc

I initially followed directions provided on github of extracting the zip to a PS accessible directory, but nothing new was accessible via get-dscresource.  After seeing the syntax outlined by the poster above, I gave manually copying the content of the DSC's source folder to the modules/SqlServerDsc root a try, and everything came back gravy fries.

All I needed was to refresh my resource since some new methods came out and couldn't remember how I did it before...  This is definitely different.